typescript complains even though it won't reach the statement
Why typescript still complains here even though we have satisfied all possible case values and it will never reach that default case?
I do this because incase  I add new string literal to the Status type and I forget to handle the new cases in switch statement it will reach the default case which return a booleanwhich is not allowed because our doSomeAction's returntype is void so typescript will warn us.
type Status = "Pending" | "Working" | "Complete";

function doSomeAction(status: Status): void {
  switch (status) {
    case "Pending":
      // some code
      break;
    case "Working":
      // some code
      break;
    case "Complete":
      // some code
      break;
    default:
      return false  //<-- Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2322)
  }
}

Edit:
I have a solution to this like this:
function doSomeAction(status: Status): void {
  switch (status) {
    ...
    ...
    default:
      neverReached(status) //typescript is happy here, no squiggly line
  }
}

function neverReached(never: never) {}

Here, typescript will only show squiggly line if we haven't handled added cases so this is what I wanted.
I just want an explanation on why typescript doesn't like the return version.

doSomeAction("wrong" as any)

I don't know why so I can't answer the question, but you can throw new Error(`Unexpected status "${status}" in doSomeAction`); instead of returning false.

Does it do what you expect if you convert the switch statement to a sequence of if/else?

TS doesn't use reachability to determine return type. There are issues like ms/TS#51800 and ms/TS#55437 where people don't like this but it's not clear anyone really wants to change it. On the face of it I'd say return false looks like a bug to me, even if it's unreachable. The standard TS approach is assertNever(), as shown here. It's based on types, not reachability. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

You return a boolean where your function return type is void. Of course it will complain.

@Quentin throwing error is for runtime, I prefer the squiggly line so we immediately see what we have overlooked

@AndreiTătar - we have satisfied all possible cases hence it will never reach the default case there

@jcalz - sorry, I just read the short comment first and tried to understand them, I will surely read yours, and I'm also doing something

Okay, no problem. Thanks!

Because it's still wrong. As @knittl noted, if someone does something unsound or if, as you mentioned, you add new cases, the case will be wrong.
From a typing perspective, false is not assignable to void, void is nothing, and false is a boolean, not a subtype of nothing. You can't pass something to nothing.
If you want to ensure you handle all possible cases, consider adding logging to catch it at runtime (or don't) or enabling typescript-eslint/switch-exhaustiveness-check to catch it at compiletime, or (as @Quentin noted) throw an error (though that might not leave the user in a nice state).
